# DNS with VPN problem

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I've been facing issues accessing company websites with the VPN and company DNS configurations set up. Access can be gained by manually adding entries to the /etc/hosts file but im looking for better fix than manualy adding each one. Resolvectl indicates that DNS requests are being handled by my local Wi-Fi connection instead of the VPN connections, none of which have DNS scopes configured. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

How can I ensure that the DNS requests are correctly routed through the VPN, and what steps can be taken to resolve the persistent issues with accessing company websites?

Comment: That depends on the VPN configuration you're using and how the VPN is configured and runs.  How do you run the VPN currently?  Network Manager or some other command line or GUI tool?

Comment: Try to add DNS-servers in your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Should help